# Array duplicating information

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

My apologies if this has been addressed - I have been searching all day and haven't found anything that meets my needs.

I have a foreach loop in php that is repeating information ad nauseum, and I am not sure how to fix it.  I have tried grouping, array_unique, etc., and haven't found a solution.  No row is a true duplicate of another when all variables are taken into account.

I have a table where each line represents a winning ticket.  Each line has a unique ID, a date, a tier (1,2,3), and some other variables worth of information.  I would like to organize this by date, ascending by tier number, where the date is listed once and each ticket is listed once.  Right now, each row is listed as a ticket, but repeats multiple times.  Here is my code - I have removed the displays in between as those work fine:

```
$selectResults = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(date) = 2014 ORDER BY date DESC, tier ASC";
$getResults = @mysqli_query($connect, $selectResults) or die('query error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
if(mysqli_num_rows($getResults) == 0){
    echo "There are no tickets to display.";
}else{
echo "<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Tier</th><th>Points</th><th>Prize Amount</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getResults)){
extract($row);
foreach($row as $ticket => $date){
    echo "<tr><td>" . date('n/j/Y', strtotime($date)) . "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    if (1 == $tier)
        {
        (Display Tier 1 tickets for date)
        }
    if (2 == $tier)
        {
        (Display Tier 2 tickets for date)
        }
    if (3 == $tier)
        {
        (Display Tier 3 tickets for date)
        }
            }
    echo "<tr class='bottomRow'><td colspan='4' /></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($row as $ticket => $date)
```

You're already looping over the rows with the `while` loop. `$row` just contains a single row, with each column as an element of the array.

Your code should look like:

```
$last_date = null;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getResults)) {
    extract($row);
    if ($date != $last_date {
        echo "<tr><td>" . date('n/j/Y', strtotime($date)) . "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        $last_date = $date;
    }
    // Display ticket details
}
```

Comment: Okay, that made it display each row once and correctly, but how can I make it group by the date in the table?  Right now, the display shows the date and the bottom row for every ticket.  I would like

    date /
    tier 1 ticket(s) for date /
    tier 2 ticket(s) for date /
    tier 3 ticket(2) for date /
    date(2) /
    etc. /
date

Comment: Set a variable to the date, and on each iteration check whether this row's date is different. Only print the date header when the date changes.